# Get all models having implemented a certain method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, methods

I have many models created with the standard rails model generator.
Some of the models have then got a method called foo().

Is there a simple way to figure out all the class names of the generated models having the foo() method implemented ?

I mean programmaticaly, from a rails controller, not from the console grepping the sourcecode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails doesn't keep an index of your models, so you'll simply have to walk your `app/models` directory.

Here's an example:

```
# Open the model directory
models_dir = Dir.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models")

# Walk directory entries
models = models_dir.collect do |filename|
  # Get the name without extension.
  # (And skip anything that isn't a Ruby file.)
  next if not filename =~ /^(.+)\.rb$/
  basename = $~[1]

  # Now, get the model class
  klass = basename.camelize.constantize

  # And return it, if it implements our method
  klass if klass.method_defined? :foo
end

# Remove nils
models.compact!
```

Rails loads your models and controllers lazily, the first time they are referenced. This is done using Ruby's `const_missing` method, and you can see all the magic happening in ActiveSupport in `active_support/dependencies.rb`.

To elaborate a bit one what's happening above, you also need to know that class names and filenames are linked. Rails expects a `ThingyBob` model to live in `thingy_bob.rb`. The way to convert between those two names is using the String method `camelize`. (The reverse would be the `underscore` method.) These String extensions are also part of ActiveSupport.

Finally, with the ActiveSupport method `constantize`, which is also a String extension, we dereference a string as a constant. So basically `"ThingyBob".constantize` is the same as just writing `ThingyBob`; we simply get the `ThingyBob` class back. In the example above,`constantize` triggers the regular dependency loading magic too.

Hope that helps demystify some things. :)